# Why is my cube distorted?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, quaternions

Using a quaternion, if I rotate my cube along an axis by 90 degrees, I get a different front facing cube side, which appears as a straight-on square of a solid color. My cube has different colored sides, so changing the axis it is rotated along gives me these different colors as expected.

When I try to rotate by an arbitrary amount, I get quite the spectacular mess, and I don't know why since I'd expect the quaternion process to work well regardless of the angle:

[image]

I am creating a quaternion from 2 vectors using this:

```
inline QuaternionT<T> QuaternionT<T>::CreateFromVectors(const Vector3<T>& v0, const    Vector3<T>& v1)
 {
if (v0 == -v1)
    return QuaternionT<T>::CreateFromAxisAngle(vec3(1, 0, 0), Pi);

Vector3<T> c = v0.Cross(v1);
T d = v0.Dot(v1);
T s = std::sqrt((1 + d) * 2);

QuaternionT<T> q;
q.x = c.x / s;
q.y = c.y / s;
q.z = c.z / s;
q.w = s / 2.0f;
return q;
}
```

I think the above method is fine since I've seen plenty of sample code correctly using it.

With the above method, I do this:

```
    Quaternion quat1=Quaternion::CreateFromVectors(vec3(0,1,0), vec3(0,0,1));
```

It works, and it is a 90-degree rotation.

But suppose I want more like a 45-degree rotation?

```
    Quaternion quat1=Quaternion::CreateFromVectors(vec3(0,1,0), vec3(0,1,1));
```

This gives me the mess above. I also tried normalizing `quat1` which provides different though similarly distorted results.

I am using the quaternion as a Modelview rotation matrix, using this:

```
inline Matrix3<T> QuaternionT<T>::ToMatrix() const
{
const T s = 2;
T xs, ys, zs;
T wx, wy, wz;
T xx, xy, xz;
T yy, yz, zz;
xs = x * s;  ys = y * s;  zs = z * s;
wx = w * xs; wy = w * ys; wz = w * zs;
xx = x * xs; xy = x * ys; xz = x * zs;
yy = y * ys; yz = y * zs; zz = z * zs;
Matrix3<T> m;
m.x.x = 1 - (yy + zz); m.y.x = xy - wz;  m.z.x = xz + wy;
m.x.y = xy + wz; m.y.y = 1 - (xx + zz); m.z.y = yz - wx;
m.x.z = xz - wy; m.y.z = yz + wx;  m.z.z = 1 - (xx + yy);
return m;
}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I guess there is some kind of problem with your depth testing. It might pay to check it!

Comment: Not related, I don't think, but I can't see how that `if (v0 == -v1)` clause is supposed to work. If I want to rotate (1,0,0) onto (-1,0,0), how can a rotation around (1,0,0) ever produce the right orientation? For that matter, how can that work for any vector which is not perpendicular to the arbitrary (1,0,0) axis?

Comment: @JasonD good question. It's not my vector library, but one that is widely used.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns widely used? That's worrying, if there are mistakes like that in there. Have you got a link?

Comment: It's quite a good book overall. Here is the link: http://amzn.to/Y7WNer perhaps it has already been pointed out on the errata for the book, or perhaps it not an error at all. i'm too new to this stuff to fully analyze it

Comment: this is already on the book's errata page: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596804831 It only works when v0 and v1 are at right angles to the X axis.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns thanks for the link. I hope not too many people are relying on that code - it's a pity the errata have not been included in an update (the downloadable code is still broken), and that one isn't even confirmed, though it's several years old. Interestingly it cites an older article in Game Programming Gems as the source of the algorithm, but I have that here and it doesn't make the same mistake!

Comment: other than that `if` statement, is the rest of the function the same as the one in Game Programming Gems?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns The original normalises the input vectors, with a note to say that this can be skipped if you know your inputs are already normalised (at least one of yours is not, in your example)

Comment: That is some real tasty sauce. I need to get my hands on that book.

Comment: @JasonD I tracked down the book and article in question. If you read the paragraph or two before the source code in the Game Programming Gems, you will see why this vector library has included the `if` statement we are discussing.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Not sure what you mean. The book highlights the problem, but notes that the fix would be to rotate 180 around a *perpendicular* axis, not around an arbitrary one. Whoever added this 'fix' either did not read, or did not understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your frustum look like? If you have a distorted "lens" such as an exceptionally wide-angle field of view, then angles that actually show the depth, such as an arbitrary rotation, might not look as you expect. (Just like how a fisheye lens on a camera makes perspective look unrealistic).

Make sure you are using a realistic frustum if you want to see realistic images.